# vb.net Set type () ()

Tags: vb.net

I have class `sObrazac` in which I have

```vb
'''<remarks/>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Primatelji", IsNullable:=false),  _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("P", IsNullable:=false, NestingLevel:=1)>  _
Public Property StranaB() As sPrimateljiP()()
    Get
        Return Me.stranaBField
    End Get
    Set
        Me.stranaBField = value
    End Set
End Property

'''<remarks/>
<System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.81.0"),  _
 System.SerializableAttribute(),  _
 System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(),  _
 System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"),  _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=true, [Namespace]:="http://e-porezna.porezna-uprava.hr/sheme/zahtjevi/ObrazacJOPPD/v1-1")>  _
Partial Public Class sPrimateljiP
    Private p1Field As Long
    Private p2Field As String
    Private p3Field As String
    Private p4Field As String
    .....
    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property P1() As Long
        Get
            Return Me.p1Field
        End Get
        Set
            Me.p1Field = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

And now I'm setting the object what I have tried

```vb
Dim oPrimatelj As New sPrimateljiP
oPrimatelj.P1 = 1
oPrimatelj.P2 = 00019
oPrimatelj.P3 = 00019
oPrimatelj.P4 = 02994650199 ....
```

After setting that object I tried to push it into list and from it to array

```vb
Dim sList As New List(Of sPrimateljiP)
sList.Add(oPrimatelj)
oObrazac.StranaB = sList.ToArray
```

But as you know it will throw me

> Value of type sPrimateljIP() cannot be converted to sPrimateljIP()()

I'm not quite familiar with two dimension arrays and I'm stuck here...

This may clear my question more. What is this element named `P`.

Note: I can't make schema, I need to adjust code to it.

[image]

Comment: Removed the C# tag as it has nothing to do with C#.

Comment: @V0ldek c# solution would be really acceptable this is .NET matter

Comment: `Public Property StranaB As sPrimateljiP()`. You have a missing container, though. It could be represented by a `Dictionary(Of String, sPrimateljiP())`

Comment: You need to do `oObrazac.StranaB = New sPrimateljiP(1)()` and then `oObrazac.StranaB(0) = sList.ToArray`

Comment: @Jimi that class is generated from xsd schema. I really can't change it because it will fail on validation.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya the part where you saying New sPrimateljiP(1)() wont go through because '{' expected

Comment: @programer Anel The C# tag reads "Use this tag for questions about code written in C# or C#'s formal specification." Feel free to tag .NET and whatever framework version you're using, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found out what solution may be thanks to comment by Chetan. Use jagged array

Push list to jagged array and set it as object

```
Dim sList As New List(Of sPrimateljiP)
sList.Add(oPrimatelj)
sList.Add(oPrimatelj)

Dim jaggedArray()() As sPrimateljiP = New sPrimateljiP(0)() {sList.ToArray}
oObrazac.StranaB = jaggedArray
```